# Refreshing div overflow scroll height with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, overflow

I have a Slider that automatically adjusts/employes a scrollbar according to the Divs height, so that if the content in a slide is larger than the container, it shows a scrollbar (overflow-y: scroll).

```
<div id="container for slider with scroll">
  <div id="with content">lots of content, show me scroll</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I load more content via Ajax into an individual div, it does not refresh the scroll height, and content is cut off. I've tried adjusting CSS styles, using clear, overflow, auto height. I have also tried refreshing the outer div with .outerHeight(true) in jquery, but I've had no luck.

An example of this problem is at http://prod.bravopublicidad.es, in **Online** or **Exterior**, clicking on "mas informacion"

Any clues or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `overflow-y: scroll` will *always* show a scrollbar. Use `overflow-y: auto` for it to only show when it is needed.

Comment: how are you loading a content inside div? that will answer your question

Comment: @manny via ajax then html(data). Doesn't this method adjust div height?

Comment: yes, directly load data inside your div, like $('#result').load('ajax/test.html');

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it's a problem at the DOM level. When more content is loaded, the metrics (height, width, etc) will get updated. Are you using some plugin to do custom scrolling or is this a pure CSS thing? If you could post a *concise* example of code which demonstrates the problem, that would help too.

---

Ok, it sounds like it's going to be a problem with the plugin you're using. I'd bet that when it's initialized, it gets the scroll height and stores it, never checking again to see if it changed. Look at the methods which that plugin provides: perhaps there will be a `reset` or `init` function which you can manually run to make it check the heights again.

Comment: I believe that the slider plugin is adjusting the height and scroll. I will try to reproduce this error in a more basic example.